# How to highlight the date in calendar with different colors according to events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my calendar java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
</script>
```

This is my view page picture of calendar

[image]

From this calendar i have  to highlight dates according to events that i have saved in the database(using colors).I don't have any idea about this.please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: yes you can highlight dates, for more info please follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300826/12853506

Comment: You are correct but they specified the date in variable.I am using ajax to get data from table and then i have to high light  the dates

Answer (score 0):

You can reinitialize the date picker in Ajax success, like this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_url" ,
success: function(response) {
    var highlight_dates = {};
    highlight_dates[ new Date( '03/10/2020' )] = new Date( '03/10/2020' );
    highlight_dates[ new Date( '02/21/2020' )] = new Date( '02/21/2020' );

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: function(date) {
          var highlight = highlight_dates[date];
            if( highlight ) {
                 return [true, "class-to-highlight", 'Special Event'];
            } else {
                 return [true, '', ''];
            }
       }
    });

} ,
});
```

Comment: You have to return only the date from Calendar table but again assigning the date